# Is there such a thing as "open" double-blind peer review?

Tags: peer-review, anonymity

Is there such a thing as "open" double-blind reviewing, where the author's comments, the reviews, and any interchange between author and reviewer are viewable, not just by the editor but also by the other reviewers, but completely anonymous?

If so, what are some journals that have this practice?

Comment: I wouldn't call it "open" to say that reviews and communication from author are visible to other reviewers. To me, "open" peer review is when those things are visible to readers of the paper, not just the reviewers. (Like [this conference](http://conferences.sigcomm.org/imc/2013/program.html), for example.)

Comment: It's common (with many journas) for all the referees to see the authors' comments and the other referee reports, when a paper is resubmitted for a second round of reviewing, although this is done at the discretion of the editor.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, there is such a thing as "open double-blind" reviewing: [the "Frontiers in" journal series](http://home.frontiersin.org/) uses exactly this model.

During the review process, "control" is handed back and forth between editors, reviewers, and authors in an incremental "conversation" model, in which the paper might go through many incremental revisions.  If the editor determines the paper cannot proceed or an author is unable to reply to reviewer comments, then it is rejected.  Otherwise, reviewers, once satisfied with the paper, sign off with an endorsement.  When all reviewers have endorsed, the paper proceeds to publication and the identity of the reviewers is revealed on the final published version.

Comment: So does the whole file get handed back and forth with each transfer?

Comment: The reviewing interface has a link to the current manuscript copy, which can be updated or not as the conversation progresses.

Comment: I am extremely frustrated that Frontiers in Public Health is burning away any reputation it has - I rather liked the idea behind their review process.